# Copy/Yank entire Lisp form in Slime

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a way to copy/yank a whole a form in Slime/Emacs?
For instance, if I have the following function:

```
(myfunc (lst)
    (myotherfunc lst))
```

I'd like to yank/copy:

```
(myotherfunc lst)
```

by issuing a keyboard shortcut when my cursor is at the opening or closing parenthesis for that form (at the point where Slime/Emacs does parenthesis matching).

Comment: I would suggest trying on stackoverflow.com too

Comment: Yes, thought I'd try here first as it is technically a superuser question...but looks like I'll have to cross-post it.

Answer (score 0):

Investigate `kill-sexp`, `mark-sexp` which are on `C-M-k` and `C-M-SPC` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try [expand-region](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el) which allows you to mark a region smartly.